# How to Bind required no of elements into one div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im new to this Jquery Stuff..

I have created many no of `div` elements..

eg:

```
<div id="inner">...</div>
<div id="inner">...</div>
<div id="inner">...</div>
.
.
.
.
.
<div id="inner">...</div>
```

so what i need is, can required no of `div` elements can be binded  or included in another `div` element? For Eg is i need 3 `div#inner` elements in one `div#outer` element and other 3 in another..

```
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">...</div>
  <div id="inner">...</div>
  <div id="inner">...</div>
</div>

<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">...</div>
  <div id="inner">...</div>
  <div id="inner">...</div>
</div>
```

So any way to make it using JQuery??

Comment: Don't give same ID to more than 1 tag an ID is unique on a page

Comment: As @pc-shooter said dont repeat ids an plz try it urself before asking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As can be seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/sY7pK/

```
var innerDivHtml = '<div class="inner"></div>';
$('div.outer').each(function(index, element){
    var i = 3;
    while(i--)
        $(element).append(innerDivHtml);
});
```

you can just append the html as a plain string to your element.

jQuery will internally transform it to `HTMLElements`.

**Note:** Don't use `id` multiple times. Use `class`. If you use `id`, only the first will be selected. `id` should be used on unique elements when you want the fastest access to them.

#### Update for your jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/vNq9M/3/

```
$(".inner").each(function(index){
    var me = $(this);
   if(index % 3 === 0)
      $('body').append('<div class="outer"></div>');
   $(".outer:last").append(me.clone());
   me.remove();
})
```

**Change from `id` to `class`**

Comment: I need inner to be binded in outer.. but not inner to be appended to outer

http://jsfiddle.net/vNq9M/

Answer (score 2):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
.outer{
    display:block;
    background:#3a3a3a;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    padding:15px;
    color:#fff;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.inner{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    background:#3a3;
    padding:3px;
    color:#fff;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {

$(".inner").each(function(index){
   if(index%3 == 0 || index == 0){
      $("#body").append("<div class='outer'></div>")
   }
   var lastOuter = $(".outer:last");
   lastOuter.append($(this).clone());
   $(this).remove();
})


});
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="inner">Inner</div>
<div class="inner">Inner</div>
<div class="inner">Inner</div>
<div class="inner">Inner</div>
<div class="inner">Inner</div>
<div class="inner">Inner</div>
<div class="inner">Inner</div>
<div class="inner">Inner</div>
<div class="inner">Inner</div>
<div id="body"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks a lot and this fixed what i needed.

`if(index % 3 == 0 || index == 0)` 

instead of

`if(index+1%3 == 0 || index == 0)`

Comment: You don't need the last `index == 0`, also in `javascript` you should use `===` instead of `==` for comparing variables of same type.

Answer (score 0):

use [clone in jquery](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

```
<div id="outer">
  <div class="inner">...</div>
  <div class="inner">...</div>
  <div class="inner">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i don't need cloning of same element but i have different elements in Different `div` section so i need only to bind it in another div

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, you can use . clone and .appendTo

```
$( ".inner" ).clone().appendTo( "#outer" );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

`$("div#outer").append("<div id='inner'>INNER</div>")`

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geoyws/hZz7f/).

If you need to create multiple inner divs, you can use a for loop:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        $("div#outer").append("<div class='innerclass'>INNERCLASS</div>");
    }
});
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geoyws/FwG4D/).